# An interval-map data structure

Tags: c++, interval, hash-map, c++17

This data structure maps values from intervals of some type `Key` which satisfies [`LessThanComparable<Key>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LessThanComparable) to values of some type `T`. I remembered this kind of data structure from an interview question.

My current use case is a distributed vector where I want to keep track which MPI rank owns which parts of some global index space.

I am not sure about the `reference_wrappers`.

### Explanation

I use a `std::map<Key, optional<T>>` where empty optionals are my sentinel for intervals, i.e. marking their end. So when mapping some interval `[0,10)` to some value `x` I do this by inserting

`map = {{0, x}, {10, {}}}`

When inserting another interval, for example `[1,3)` to `y` this is going to be

`map = {{0, x}, {1, y}, {3, x}, {10, {}}}`

### Usage

[Here is a link to wandbox running the code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cwWjlJiRbNpdCLnC)

```
#include "fub/IntervalMap.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::ostream& out, const std::map<int, std::optional<std::string>>& map)
{
  for (auto&& [key, mapped] : map)
  {
    out << '{' << key << ", ";
    if (mapped.has_value()) {
      out << *mapped;
    } else {
      out << "{}";
    }
    out << "}\n";
  }
  out << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  auto map = fub::IntervalMap<int, std::string>{};

  map.insert(0, 10, "foo");
  print(std::cout, map.std_map());
  std::cout << "map.at(0) = " << map.at(0) << '\n';
  std::cout << "map[10].has_value() = " << map[10].has_value() << "\n\n";

  map.insert(3, 7, "bar");
  print(std::cout, map.std_map());
  std::cout << "map.at(5) = " << map.at(5) << "\n\n";

  map.remove(2, 8);
  print(std::cout, map.std_map());
  std::cout << "map[5].has_value() = " << map[5].has_value() << '\n';
}
```

### Output

```
{0, foo}
{10, {}}

map.at(0) = foo
map[10].has_value() = false

{0, foo}
{3, bar}
{7, foo}
{10, {}}

map.at(5) = bar

{0, foo}
{2, {}}
{8, foo}
{10, {}}

map[5].has_value() = false
```

### Relevant source code

```
#ifndef FUB_INTERVALMAP_HPP
#define FUB_INTERVALMAP_HPP

#include <map>
#include <optional>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace fub
{
  template <
      typename Key,
      typename T,
      typename Compare = std::less<Key>,
      typename Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, std::optional<T>>>
  > class IntervalMap
  {
    private:
      using map_type = std::map<Key, std::optional<T>, Compare, Allocator>;
      map_type map_;

    public:

      // CONSTRUCTORS

      IntervalMap()
      noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<map_type>)
        : IntervalMap{Compare()}
      {}

      explicit
      IntervalMap(const Compare& comp, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
      noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<map_type>)
        : map_{comp, alloc}
      {}

      IntervalMap(const IntervalMap&) = default;

      IntervalMap(const IntervalMap& other, const Allocator& alloc)
        : map_{other.map_, alloc}
      {}

      IntervalMap(IntervalMap&&) = default;

      IntervalMap(IntervalMap&& other, const Allocator& alloc)
      noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<map_type>)
        : map_{std::move(other.map_), alloc}
      {}

      ~IntervalMap() = default;

      IntervalMap& operator=(const IntervalMap&) = default;

      IntervalMap& operator=(IntervalMap&&) = default;

      // ACCESSORS

      const map_type&
      std_map() const&
      noexcept
      { return map_; }

      std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>>
      operator[](const Key& key) const&
      noexcept(std::is_nothrow_callable_v<Compare(const Key&, const Key&)>)
      {
        auto ub = map_.upper_bound(key);
        if (ub == map_.begin()) {
          return {};
        }
        return (--ub)->second;
      }

      const T&
      at(const Key& key) const&
      {
        auto ub = this->operator[](key);
        if (!ub.has_value()) {
          throw std::out_of_range {
            "IntervalMap::at: index is out of bounds."
          };
        }
        return *ub;
      }

      // CAPACITY

      bool
      empty() const
      noexcept
      {
        return map_.empty();
      }

      // MODIFIERS

      /// \brief assigns a `value` to a given interval [lower, upper).
      /// \note `T` needs to be `CopyConstructible` for `insert_upper_bound`
      void
      insert(Key lower, Key upper, T value)
      {
        if (!compare(lower, upper)) {
          return;
        }
        auto last = insert_upper_bound(std::move(upper));
        auto first = map_.lower_bound(lower);
        map_.erase(first, last);
        map_.insert(last, std::make_pair(std::move(lower), std::move(value)));
      }

      /// \brief removes all values in the given interval [lower, upper).
      /// \note this requires that `T` is `CopyConstructible`
      void
      remove(Key lower_key, Key upper_key)
      {
        if (!compare(lower_key, upper_key)) {
          return;
        }
        auto first = map_.lower_bound(lower_key);
        auto last  = map_.upper_bound(upper_key);
        if (last != map_.begin()) {
          auto prev = std::prev(last);
          last = map_.insert(last, std::make_pair(std::move(upper_key), prev->second));
        }
        if (first == map_.begin() || !has_value(std::prev(first))) {
          map_.erase(first, last);
        } else {
          first = map_.insert(first, std::make_pair(std::move(lower_key), std::optional<T>()));
          first->second.reset();
          map_.erase(std::next(first), last);
        }
        erase_if_empty(last);
      }


    private:
      /// \brief compares to key values with maps comparator
      bool
      compare(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) const
      noexcept(std::is_nothrow_callable_v<Compare(Key, Key)>)
      { return std::invoke(map_.key_comp(), lhs, rhs); }

      /// \brief inserts an upper bound such that super sets are valid
      /// \note this is a helper function for `insert()`
      /// \note `T` needs to be `CopyConstructible`
      auto insert_upper_bound(Key&& upper)
      {
        auto last = map_.upper_bound(upper);
        if (last == map_.begin()) {
          return map_.insert(last, std::make_pair(std::move(upper), std::optional<T>{}));
        }
        auto&& value_before = std::prev(last)->second;
        return map_.insert(last, std::make_pair(std::move(upper), value_before));
      }

      /// \brief tests if there is a value at the given position.
      /// \note iterator has to be deferencable
      bool
      has_value(typename map_type::const_iterator iterator) const
      noexcept
      { return iterator->second.has_value(); }

      /// \brief erases the iterator if it points to an empty optional.
      /// \note if the optional is empty the iterator is a pure upper bound.
      /// \note this function is a helper function for `remove()`
      void
      erase_if_empty(typename map_type::const_iterator iterator)
      noexcept
      {
        if (iterator != map_.end() && !has_value(iterator)) {
          map_.erase(iterator);
        }
      }
  };

  template <typename Key, typename T, typename Comp, typename Allocator>
    bool operator==(
        const IntervalMap<Key, T, Comp, Allocator>& lhs,
        const IntervalMap<Key, T, Comp, Allocator>& rhs)
    {
      return lhs.map() == rhs.map();
    }

  template <typename Key, typename T, typename Comp, typename Allocator>
    bool operator!=(
        const IntervalMap<Key, T, Comp, Allocator>& lhs,
        const IntervalMap<Key, T, Comp, Allocator>& rhs)
    {
      return lhs.map() != rhs.map();
    }

}

#endif // !INTERVALMAP_HPP
```

Comment: Did you mean `ComparableLessThan`...?

Comment: Oh yeah. I actually mean `LessThanComparable`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LessThanComparable. But what really is meant, is that `Compare` is a predicate on `Key`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a good grasp of non trivial concepts, but then you produce very over-engineered code.

[Please see my refactoring here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DgslCKOZRZoPcQ4C) as well as below.

Also, yes you remembered the interview question, but it seems, not all of it. There is a requirement that adjacent values can not be inserted.  If the situation is:

(0,'A')(6, 'B')(42,'A')

it is not allowed to insert (6,41,'A') ... as there are "value clashes" on both sides.

Also the interval size is bound. 0 .. SIZE

Finally. I have made C++ solution where Key and Value, are both (non trivial) classes. Then I have made pure C solution which I like more. It is simpler. Not faster for very large SIZE's but fast enough.

Here is the whole of the refactoring of your solution:

```
    // dbj.org 2018 DEC
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <optional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
// terminating error
inline void terror( bool rez, const char * msg ) {
  if ( rez) return ;
  assert(msg);
  perror(msg);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
}
#define ST_(x) #x
#define ST(x) ST_(x)
#define TT(x) std::cout << std::endl << ST(x) << std::endl ; (x)
#define dbj_verify(x) terror(x, "\n\n" __FILE__ "(" ST(__LINE__) ")\n\tERROR: " ST(x) " -- evaluated to false\n\n")

// this
// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158341/an-interval-map-data-structure
// refactored and hopefully simplified and improved
namespace fub
{
  template <
      typename Key,
      typename T
      /*
      DBJ moved this to be public typedefs usabel by template definitions clients
      typename Compare = std::less<Key>,
      typename Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, std::optional<T>>>
      */
  > class IntervalMap final /* DBJ added 'final' */
  {
      // DBJ -- typedef are to be public and thus used by the client code
      // this is standard C++ standard convention
      public:
      // DBJ moved these two from template parameters so that client code can use them
      // using Compare = std::less<Key>;
      // using Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, std::optional<T>>>;
    // DBJ removed --> private:
      // using map_type = std::map<Key, std::optional<T>, Compare, Allocator>;
      using map_type = std::map<Key, std::optional<T> >;
      map_type map_;
      // DBJ 00: this much simplifies methods inside the template
      using type = IntervalMap ;

      // DBJ 01: using static_assert simplifies the code
      // check the type requirements only once at compile time
      // no need to mention them in every comment
      static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<map_type>);
      static_assert(is_copy_constructible_v <T> ) ;

     // DBJ removed --> public:
/*
      IntervalMap()
      // DBJ removed. See DBJ 01 -- noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<map_type>) 
        : IntervalMap{Compare()}
      {}

      explicit
      IntervalMap(const Compare& comp, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
      // DBJ removed. See DBJ 01 -- noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<map_type>) 
        : map_{comp, alloc}
      {}

      IntervalMap(const IntervalMap&) = default;

      IntervalMap(const IntervalMap& other, const Allocator& alloc)
        : map_{other.map_, alloc}
      {}

      IntervalMap(IntervalMap&& other, const Allocator& alloc)
      // DBJ removed. See DBJ 01 -- noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<map_type>) 
        : map_{std::move(other.map_), alloc}
      {}
*/
      /* DBJ 02: commented out -- reason: this is not necessary
      ~IntervalMap() = default;
      IntervalMap& operator=(const IntervalMap&) = default;
      IntervalMap& operator=(IntervalMap&&) = default;
      IntervalMap(IntervalMap&&) = default;
       */
      // ACCESSORS

      //DBJ 03: commented out -- reasone: compiler will do the most efficient move/copy elision
      // stanbdard C++ is based on value semantics
      // no need to return by const reference
      // const map_type&  std_map() const&   noexcept     { return map_; }
      map_type  std_map() const  noexcept  { return map_; }

      // DBJ 04: removed use of reference_wrapper -- reason:  see DBJ 03
      // std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>>
      std::optional<T>
      operator[](const Key& key) const // DBJ removed --> & 
          // DBJ removed, see DBJ 01 -- noexcept(std::is_nothrow_callable_v<Compare(const Key&, const Key&)>)
      {
        auto ub = map_.upper_bound(key);
        if (ub == map_.begin()) {
          return {};
        }
        return (--ub)->second;
      }

      //DBJ 05: removed -- reason const & not necessary in standard C++
      // const T & at(const Key& key) const&
      T  at(Key key) const
      {
        auto ub = this->operator[](key);
        if (!ub.has_value()) {
          throw std::out_of_range {
            "IntervalMap::at: index is out of bounds."
          };
        }
        return *ub;
      }

      // CAPACITY

      bool  empty() const  noexcept  { return map_.empty(); }

      // MODIFIERS

      /// \brief assigns a `value` to a given interval [lower, upper).
      /// \note `T` needs to be `CopyConstructible` for `insert_upper_bound`
      /// DBJ: no need to emphasize this in every comment, see DBJ 01
      void
      insert(Key lower, Key upper, T value)
      {
        if (!compare(lower, upper)) {
          return;
        }
        auto last = insert_upper_bound(std::move(upper));
        auto first = map_.lower_bound(lower);
        map_.erase(first, last);
        map_.insert(last, std::make_pair(std::move(lower), std::move(value)));
      }

      /// \brief removes all values in the given interval [lower, upper).
      /// \note this requires that `T` is `CopyConstructible`
      /// DBJ: no need to emphasize this in every comment, see DBJ 01
      void
      remove(Key lower_key, Key upper_key)
      {
        if (!compare(lower_key, upper_key)) {
          return;
        }
           auto upper_ = map_.find(upper_key);
           auto current_ = map_.find(lower_key);
               while( (current_ != map_.end())  || (current_ != upper_ )) 
               {
                  auto next_ = next(current_);
                      map_.erase(current_) ;
                  current_ = next_ ;    
               }
           if(upper_ != map_.end())
                    map_.erase(upper_);
      }


    private:
      /// \brief compares to key values with maps comparator
      /// DBJ: the comment above is completely confusing
      // obvously jus two keys are compared, between  thmeselves
      // also and again const references are not an optimization 
      // bool  compare(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) const
      // as this is standard C++
      // also DBJ -- see DBJ 01 -- noexcept(std::is_nothrow_callable_v<Compare(Key, Key)>)
      bool  compare(Key lhs, Key rhs) const
      { 
          // DBJ removed --> return std::invoke(map_.key_comp(), lhs, rhs); 
          // we have defined the Compare type in the template prologue
          // although it is not clear why? 
          return lhs < rhs ;
      }

      /// \brief inserts an upper bound such that super sets are valid
      /// \note this is a helper function for `insert()`
      /// \note `T` needs to be `CopyConstructible`
      /// DBJ: no need to emphasize this in every comment, see DBJ 01
      /// DBJ removed the use of r-refernce -- auto insert_upper_bound(Key&& upper)
      auto insert_upper_bound(Key upper)
      {
        auto last = map_.upper_bound(upper);
        if (last == map_.begin()) {
          return map_.insert(last, std::make_pair(std::move(upper), std::optional<T>{}));
        }
        auto&& value_before = std::prev(last)->second;
        return map_.insert(last, std::make_pair(std::move(upper), value_before));
      }

      /// \brief tests if there is a value at the given position.
      /// \note iterator has to be deferencable
      bool  has_value(typename map_type::const_iterator iterator) const  noexcept
      { 
      return iterator->second.has_value(); 
      }

      /// \brief erases the iterator if it points to an empty optional.
      /// \note if the optional is empty the iterator is a pure upper bound.
      /// \note this function is a helper function for `remove()`
      void erase_if_empty(typename map_type::const_iterator iterator)  noexcept
      {
      /*
      DBJ commented out
        if (iterator != map_.end() && !has_value(iterator)) {
          map_.erase(iterator);
       */
        if (iterator == map_.end() ) return ;
        if ( has_value(iterator) ) return ;
          map_.erase(iterator);
      }

    // DBJ moved these two in here and made them friends
friend  bool operator==( const type & lhs, const type & rhs)
    {
      return lhs.map() == rhs.map();
    }

friend  bool operator!=( const type & lhs, const type & rhs)
    {
      return ! ( lhs.map() == rhs.map() );
    }

  }; // DBJ added comment --> eof IntervalMap
/*
DBJ commented out -- reason -- 1. these are much simple if made as friend's to the IntervalMap
                               2. they both need not have full implementeation  as not_eqauls
                                  is ! equals ... see above 
  template <typename Key, typename T, typename Comp, typename Allocator>
    bool operator==(
        const IntervalMap<Key, T, Comp, Allocator>& lhs,
        const IntervalMap<Key, T, Comp, Allocator>& rhs)
    {
      return lhs.map() == rhs.map();
    }

  template <typename Key, typename T, typename Comp, typename Allocator>
    bool operator!=(
        const IntervalMap<Key, T, Comp, Allocator>& lhs,
        const IntervalMap<Key, T, Comp, Allocator>& rhs)
    {
      return lhs.map() != rhs.map();
    }
*/
} // DBJ added comment -> eof namespace 

// void print(std::ostream& out, const std::map<int, std::optional<std::string>>& map)
// DBH changed to std ostream operator handling the required map type
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const std::map<int, std::optional<std::string>>& map)
{
  for (auto&& [key, mapped] : map)
  {
    out << '{' << key << ", ";
    if (mapped.has_value()) {
      out << *mapped;
    } else {
      out << "{}";
    }
    out << "}\n";
  }
  out << '\n';
    return out ;
}

// DBJ added
using fub_interval_map_type = fub::IntervalMap<int, string> ;

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const fub_interval_map_type & fub_map)
{
    return out << fub_map.std_map();
}

int main()
{
  cout << boolalpha;
  auto map = fub_interval_map_type{} ;

 TT(map.insert(0, 10, "foo"));
  cout << map << "map.at(0) = " << map.at(0) << '\n';
  cout << "map[10].has_value() = " << map[10].has_value() << "\n\n";

  TT(map.insert(3, 7, "bar"));
  cout <<  map << "map.at(5) = " << map.at(5) << "\n\n";

  TT(map.remove(2, 8));
  cout <<  map << "map[5].has_value() = " << map[5].has_value() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: It's better to present proposed improvements in the body of your answer, rather than pointing to external sites without explanation.  Please incorporate those suggestions into your answer (keep the link as additional information if you feel it helps, but don't make your answer useless without it).  Thanks.